# Query is giving result in count but not showing in table

Tags: php, pdo

So my query says there is 1 message but it does not show up in the table

**The query**

```
<?php
//Unread
$req1 = $db->query('
                      SELECT
                          m1.id,
                          m1.title, 
                          m1.timestamp, 
                          m1.user1,
                          m1.user2,                          
                          m2.id as reps, 
                          blog_users.username
                      FROM 
                          pm as m1, 
                          pm as m2,
                          blog_users 
                      WHERE 
                         ((m1.user1="'.$session->username.'" and m1.user1read="no" and blog_users.username=m1.user2) 
                      OR 
                          (m1.user2="'.$session->username.'" and m1.user2read="no" and blog_users.username=m1.user1)) and m1.id2="1" and m2.id=m1.id 
                      group by 
                           m1.id 
                      order by 
                           m1.id desc');
$req1->execute();
$req1c = $req1->fetchAll();
$result = $req1->rowCount();


  print_r($req1->errorInfo());  
    ?>
```

**Result of errorinfo**

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

**Posting table**

```
<?php
//We display the list of unread messages
while($dn1 = $req1->fetch())
{

?>
    <tr>
        <td class="left"><a href="read_pm.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $dn1['reps']-1; ?></td>
        <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn1['timestamp']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

?>
```

It should show the 1 message but it is not showing it. Also it's weird that it is not showing because there is a result in mysql.

Comment: What is this line `$req1c = $req1->fetchAll();` for?

Comment: @YourCommonSense `<h3>Unread Messages(<?php echo count($req1c); ?>):</h3>`

Comment: Don't you have this count in `$result` already?

Comment: @YourCommonSense That 1 is being used in the "you have no unread message's" part. But because i dont see that message in the page there is a pm so i its not needed in the question

Comment: Well, if you don't need that fetchAll() part, why it's in the code then? May be just get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because fetchAll() is setting the resource pointer to the end of the result set, so by the time you get to your while loop the result thinks there are no rows left to fetch.

I think there is a rewind() method on the result object, but you'd probably be better off assigning the result of fetchAll() to an array and iterate over that in the "posting table" script instead.